# How to remove kubernetes pods related files from file system?

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes.
So, I created few pods.
Then I deleted all pods using

kubectl delete pods --all

But output of `df -h` still shows kubernetes consumed disk space.

```sh
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       194G   19G  175G  10% /
devtmpfs        7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G  2.2M  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2246
/dev/loop1       25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
/dev/loop3       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2253
/dev/loop4       68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/loop5       44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14295
/dev/loop6       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1242
/dev/loop7       43M   43M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14066
/dev/loop8       68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21803
/dev/loop9       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1270
tmpfs           1.6G   20K  1.6G   1% /run/user/123
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a2054657-e24d-434f-8ba5-b93813a405fc/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/local-path-provisioner-service-account-token-4hkj6
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/fa06c678-814f-4f98-8d2d-806e85923830/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/metrics-server-token-pjbwh
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/daceb65d912a45e87d29955b499aff1d7fbc40584eade7903a75a2c5a317325a/shm
overlay         194G   19G  175G  10% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/daceb65d912a45e87d29955b499aff1d7fbc40584eade7903a75a2c5a317325a/rootfs
overlay         194G   19G  175G  10% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/956d3b341a87e4232792ebf1ad0925f07c180d6d86de149a6ec801f74c0b47f8/rootfs
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/374537a007565bba5b00824576d35e2f2ee8835c354205748117b6622dc68a6d/shm
overlay         194G   19G  175G  10% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/374537a007565bba5b00824576d35e2f2ee8835c354205748117b6622dc68a6d/rootfs
overlay         194G   19G  175G  10% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/babfe080e5ec18297a219e65f99d6156fbd8b8651950a63052606ffebd7a618a/rootfs
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4e3b15c1-f051-42eb-a3d1-9b3de38dae12/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-lnpwv
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/df53096e-f89b-4fc7-ab8a-672d841ac44f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/coredns-token-sxtjn
tmpfs           7.8G  8.0K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/415a1140-5813-48cf-bd88-17b647bd955c/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/ssl
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/415a1140-5813-48cf-bd88-17b647bd955c/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/traefik-token-46qmp
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/d29d1a4a1ac25c92618ff9294e9045a1e2333899f64c3935c5e9955b7d1b3e61/shm
overlay         194G   19G  175G  10% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d29d1a4a1ac25c92618ff9294e9045a1e2333899f64c3935c5e9955b7d1b3e61/rootfs
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/2ad63b79faa95666c75dfa397524c4ed5464acfebf577c388e19ae5fc349c0c8/shm
overlay         194G   19G  175G  10% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/2ad63b79faa95666c75dfa397524c4ed5464acfebf577c388e19ae5fc349c0c8/rootfs
overlay         194G   19G  175G  10% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/39b88e479947c9240a7c5233555c7a19b29f3ccc7bd1da117251c8e8959aca3c/rootfs
shm              64M     0   64M   0%
```

What are these spaces showing in df -h ? How to free up these spaces ?

EDIT:

I noticed that pods are restarting after I delete them.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mylab-airflow-redis-0                      1/1     Running   0          33m
mylab-airflow-postgresql-0                 1/1     Running   0          34m
mylab-postgresql-0                         1/1     Running   0          34m
mylab-keyclo-0                             1/1     Running   0          34m
mylab-keycloak-postgres-0                  1/1     Running   0          34m
mylab-airflow-scheduler-788f7f4dd6-ppg6v   2/2     Running   0          34m
mylab-airflow-worker-0                     2/2     Running   0          34m
mylab-airflow-flower-6d8585794d-s2jzd      1/1     Running   0          34m
mylab-airflow-webserver-859766684b-w9zcm   1/1     Running   0          34m
mylab-5f7d84fcbc-59mkf                     1/1     Running   0          34m
```

**Edited**

So I deleted the deployments.

```
kubectl delete deployment --all
```

Now, there are no deployments.

```
$ kubectl get deployment
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Then after, I stopped the cluster.

```
systemctl stop k3s
```

**Disk space is still not released.**

Output of latest disk usage.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       194G   35G  160G  18% /
devtmpfs        7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G  2.5M  1.6G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2246
/dev/loop1       25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
/dev/loop3       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2253
/dev/loop4       68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/loop5       44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14295
/dev/loop6       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1242
/dev/loop7       43M   43M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14066
/dev/loop8       68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21803
/dev/loop9       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1270
tmpfs           1.6G   20K  1.6G   1% /run/user/123
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/a2054657-e24d-434f-8ba5-b93813a405fc/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/local-path-provisioner-service-account-token-4hkj6
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/fa06c678-814f-4f98-8d2d-806e85923830/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/metrics-server-token-pjbwh
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/daceb65d912a45e87d29955b499aff1d7fbc40584eade7903a75a2c5a317325a/shm
overlay         194G   35G  160G  18% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/daceb65d912a45e87d29955b499aff1d7fbc40584eade7903a75a2c5a317325a/rootfs
overlay         194G   35G  160G  18% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/956d3b341a87e4232792ebf1ad0925f07c180d6d86de149a6ec801f74c0b47f8/rootfs
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/374537a007565bba5b00824576d35e2f2ee8835c354205748117b6622dc68a6d/shm
overlay         194G   35G  160G  18% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/374537a007565bba5b00824576d35e2f2ee8835c354205748117b6622dc68a6d/rootfs
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/4e3b15c1-f051-42eb-a3d1-9b3de38dae12/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/default-token-lnpwv
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/df53096e-f89b-4fc7-ab8a-672d841ac44f/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/coredns-token-sxtjn
tmpfs           7.8G  8.0K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/415a1140-5813-48cf-bd88-17b647bd955c/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/ssl
tmpfs           7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /var/lib/kubelet/pods/415a1140-5813-48cf-bd88-17b647bd955c/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/traefik-token-46qmp
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/d29d1a4a1ac25c92618ff9294e9045a1e2333899f64c3935c5e9955b7d1b3e61/shm
overlay         194G   35G  160G  18% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/d29d1a4a1ac25c92618ff9294e9045a1e2333899f64c3935c5e9955b7d1b3e61/rootfs
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/2ad63b79faa95666c75dfa397524c4ed5464acfebf577c388e19ae5fc349c0c8/shm
overlay         194G   35G  160G  18% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/2ad63b79faa95666c75dfa397524c4ed5464acfebf577c388e19ae5fc349c0c8/rootfs
overlay         194G   35G  160G  18% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/39b88e479947c9240a7c5233555c7a19b29f3ccc7bd1da117251c8e8959aca3c/rootfs
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri/sandboxes/6eddeab3511cf326a530dd042f5348978c6ba98bf8d595c2936cb6f56e30f754/shm
overlay         194G   35G  160G  18% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/6eddeab3511cf326a530dd042f5348978c6ba98bf8d595c2936cb6f56e30f754/rootfs
overlay         194G   35G  160G  18% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/78568d4850964c9c7b8ca5df11bf532a477492119813094631641132aadd23a0/rootfs
overlay         194G   35G  160G  18% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/14d87054e0c7a2a86ae64be70a79f94e2d193bc4739d97e261e85041c160f3bc/rootfs
overlay         194G   35G  160G  18% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/0971fe44fc6f0f5c9e0b8c1a0e3279c20b3bc574e03d12607644e1e7d427ff65/rootfs
tmpfs           1.6G  4.0K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Output of `ctr containers ls`

```
# ctr container list
CONTAINER    IMAGE    RUNTIME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mandatory data to be maintain when a cluster is running (eg. default service token). When you shutdown (eg. systemctl stop k3s) the cluster (not just delete pods) these will be released.

Comment: `systemctl stop and_what_here? `

Comment: Got this :
`Failed to stop kubelet.service: Unit kubelet.service not loaded.`

Comment: I see that the pods I deleted have restarted again. How to permanently stop them ?

Comment: Run `systemctl stop k3s`. To stop it permanently do `systemctl disable k3s`

Comment: Disabled `k3s` like you said. I can confirm k3s is not running. Still the space is not cleared.

Comment: Output of `df -h` is same as before.

Comment: and `kubectl get pods`?

Comment: output of get pods
`The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

Comment: Ok. Your cluster has been shutdown, working space taken by your cluster control plane will be released, since you had deleted all pods.

Comment: When will it be released ? Does it take some time ? Should it not be released right away ?

Comment: did you update your question? note deleted pods that were managed by a deployment will be restarted. In this case, you **did not** delete any pod and the space used to keep the container will remain.

Comment: What is the proper way to delete the pods and release the storage then ? I already tried `systemctl disable k3s` but that doesn't release space either

Comment: You need to bring back your cluster `systemctl start k3s`, list what you have deployed before eg. `kubectl get deployment`, and `kubetl delete deployment <name>`. Finally stop your cluster as the above instruction.

Comment: Deleted deployment, stopped cluster. Storage is not released yet. P.S I have edited the question.

Comment: Can you update your question with latest disk usage info?

Comment: And the output of `ctr containers ls`

Comment: I have updated the question with latest disk usage info.

Comment: So which is consumed physical disk space? You aware what is tmpfs, shm & overlay? These are not referring to your physical disk space.

Comment: Oh. I was not aware tmpfs, shm & overlay do not refer to physical disk space. How can I remove them anyway ? Do I have to completely uninstall k3s for this ?

Comment: systemd will take care of that, you should leave them alone. Your k3s has been disabled, it should not start the next time you restart your machine. Keeping or remove k3s does not change those entries now. You can try restart your machine.